# Accessing field of Abstract class from derived classes

Tags: oop, groovy

I am trying to abstract the methods and field from two concrete classes. I am not sure about the field in the abstract class..

Will `SearchFactory` and `WorkFactory` be accessing the same `products` field if I try to make them Singleton objects? But if I create new instances of the concrete factories, the `products` is a new isolated field for different instances right?

**SlashCommand**

```
interface SlashCommand {

}
```

**SlashCommandFactory**

```
abstract class SlashCommandFactory {
    protected HashMap<String, SlashCommand> products

    SlashCommand getProduct( String key ) {
        products.key
    }

    void registerProduct( String key, String value ) {
        products << [ key: value ]
    }
}
```

**SearchFactory**

```
class SearchFactory extends SlashCommandFactory {

}
```

**WorkFactory**

```
class WorkFactory extends SlashCommandFactory {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your products `Map` is `static`, which means that it will be the same objects across all instances of the class. It belongs to the *class*, not to the *object*.

You won't be able to access the field if you set its access modifier to `private`. Change it to `protected` to directly access it from subclasses.

Comment: Oops I forgot to change that to non-static and protected or no access modifier. With the edited code, Does it mean that 'products' is not shared between WorkFactory and SearchFactory and they have their own copy?